# Drupal Commerce: How to theme Product Field

Tags: theming, commerce

[image: Drupal Commerce Product Display Node]

On the product display node of Drupal commerce, you have the "Product field".
This displays all the products that are attached to the product display.
The products are displayed in a drop down menu.

By default, any fields on the product are displayed above the drop down menu. How can I theme this field, so the field are displayed below the drop down menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured this out.

1) Create a file named:  `node--NAME-OF-CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php`

2) Insert the following in the file:

```
<?php print render($content['field_product']); ?>
<?php print render($content['product:NAME-OF-FIELD-ATTACHED-TO-PRODUCT']); ?>
```

`<?php print render($content['field_product']); ?>` is the add to cart drop down menu, so if you put the fields below it, they will appear under the add to cart drop down menu.

3) Clear cahces (at YOURSITE.com/admin/config/development/performance)